# typeerror: 'float' object is not iterable in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration, typeerror

I have `Md = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60]`
and point with latitude `Amp_lat = 1.98` and longitude `Amp_lon = 30.03` but I am trying to run the following code but I am getting this error

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

```
for distkm in (Md):
    Center = Amp_lat, Amp_lon
    North = vincenty(kilometers=distKm).destination(Point(Amp_lat, Amp_lon), 0).format_decimal()
    East = vincenty(kilometers=distKm).destination(Point(Amp_lat, Amp_lon), 90).format_decimal()
    South = vincenty(kilometers=distKm).destination(Point(Amp_lat, Amp_lon), 180).format_decimal()
    West = vincenty(kilometers=distKm).destination(Point(Amp_lat, Amp_lon), 270).format_decimal()
```

Comment: Can you parse the full tracelog?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'd like to see the full code, but I guess the error comes from `vincenty` what type is it?

Comment: Md is a list so you should be able to iterate over it like you have it... so you must have something else assigned to Md than you expect.. like maybe 1.98?

Comment: Hi Berbason, welcome to both worlds of python and stackoverflow :)
Do you know that python is case sensitive? I could see that you used a variable that is all in small letters: "distkm", then inside the loop you used a variable with the same letters yet capital K: "distKm"

Answer (score 0):

Try **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**, it is more convenient:

```
new = [[k] for k in A]
```

**Explanation**

You are getting ***TypeError*** because you cannot apply list() function to the value of type float. This function takes an iterable as a parameter and float are not iterable.